# printf method to create a header

Tags: java, printf

I would like to know how i can use the printf method to create a header for my columns :

```
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select country_id,country_name,region_id,last_name from countries");

    while (rset.next())
        System.out.printf("%-5s %-25s %5s \n", rset.getString("country_id"),rset.getString("country_name"),rset.getString("region_id"));

    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
```

the output is this and i want a header above each column! how can i do this?

```
AR    Argentina                     2 
AU    Australia                     3 
BE    Belgium                       1 
BR    Brazil                        2 
CA    Canada                        2 
CH    Switzerland                   1 
CN    China                         3 
DE    Germany                       1 
DK    Denmark                       1 
EG    Egypt                         4 
FR    France                        1 
IL    Israel                        4 
IN    India                         3 
IT    Italy                         1 
JP    Japan                         3 
KW    Kuwait                        4 
ML    Malaysia                      3 
MX    Mexico                        2 
NG    Nigeria                       4 
NL    Netherlands                   1 
SG    Singapore                     3 
UK    United Kingdom                1 
US    United States of America      2 
ZM    Zambia                        4 
ZW    Zimbabwe                      4
```

Comment: Each column? Or you want to have a header above all the columns?

Comment: where AR AU BE BR CA etc is one column! Argentina Aystralia Belgium Brazil etc is another.. i want a header over those columns!

Comment: no i need each column! so i want 3 headers!

Answer (score 1):

Just print it before the loop

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select country_id,country_name,region_id,last_name from countries");

System.out.printf("%-5s %-25s %5s \n", "country_id","country_name","region_id");
while (rset.next())

    System.out.printf("%-5s %-25s %5s \n", rset.getString("country_id"),rset.getString("country_name"),rset.getString("region_id"));
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd just have another `System.out.println()` statement, like so:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select country_id,country_name,region_id,last_name from countries");
System.out.printf("%-5s %-25s %5s \n", "Country Id", "Name", "Region Id");
while (rset.next())

System.out.printf("%-5s %-25s %5s \n", rset.getString("country_id"),rset.getString("country_name"),rset.getString("region_id"));
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a general header for all the columns as whole you should print it like:

```
System.out.println("Country_ID Country_Name Region_ID");
```

Add this before the `while` loop.

Or if you are looking for printing the same header before each line of groups of columns,you should try this:

```
while (rset.next())
    {

        System.out.println("Country_ID Country_Name Region_ID");
        System.out.printf("%-5s %-25s %5s \n", rset.getString("country_id"),rset.getString("country_name"),rset.getString("region_id"));
    }
```

Comment: @user2985600 Please mark it as answer if it was what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select country_id,country_name,region_id,last_name from countries");
    System.out.printf("%-5s %-25s %5s \n", "Country Id", "Name", "Region Id");
    while (rset.next())

    System.out.printf("%-5s %-25s %5s \n", rset.getString("country_id"),rset.getString("country_name"),rset.getString("region_id"));
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select country_id,country_name,region_id,last_name from countries");

System.out.printf("%-5s %-25s %5s \n", "country_id","country_name","region_id");

System.out.printf("%-5s %-25s %5s \n", "----------","------------","---------");
while (rset.next())
System.out.printf("%-5s %-25s %5s \n", rset.getString("country_id"),rset.getString("country_name"),rset.getString("region_id"));
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```